# Shiny plot is outside the dashboardBody

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

Please see attached image. Do you have suggestions how to avoid that the plot is outside the white area, or to make the grey area below the plot white?

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  # Application title
  dashboardHeader(title=h4(HTML("Virus Coverage plot"))),
  dashboardSidebar(
    useShinyjs(),
    
    selectInput("Taxa", "Taxa", choices = unique(files.Vir.DNA.df.test$V1))
  ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Taxa", plotOutput("myplot1"))
      
    )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data_selected <- reactive({
    filter(files.Vir.DNA.df.test, V1 %in% input$Taxa)
  })
  
  output$myplot1 <- renderPlot({
   #data_selected() %>%
    #  filter(Cancer=="Anus" | Cancer=="Cervix") %>%
        p <- ggplot(data_selected(),aes(position,rowSums, fill = V1)) + 
        #theme_bw(base_size = 6) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity") +
        facet_grid(Cancer~. , scales = "free_x", space = "free_x", switch = "x") +
        theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0),
            strip.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
            strip.background = element_rect(colour = "transparent", fill = "transparent"),
            plot.background = element_rect(colour = "white", fill = "white"),
            panel.background = element_rect(colour = "white", fill = "white"),
            
            axis.text.x = element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) + 
      labs(y="Sum coverage within cancer type", x="", title="") +
      scale_fill_manual(values=mycolors) + 
      theme(legend.position = "none") 
      #scale_y_log10() 
      print(p)
  },res = 100,width = 600, height = 1200)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example isn't reproducible - so I made a new one.

You just need to wrap the `plotOutput` in a `fluidRow`:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(datasets)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  # dashboardBody(plotOutput("myplot")) # exceeds body
  dashboardBody(fluidRow(plotOutput("myplot"))) # works
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    scatter <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) 
    scatter + geom_point(aes(color=Species, shape=Species)) +
      xlab("Sepal Length") +  ylab("Sepal Width") +
      ggtitle("Sepal Length-Width")
  }, height = 1200)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```